# Plot x=3 in PGFPlots

Tags: pgfplots, diagrams, pgfmath

I just started to use `pgfplots` and I'm trying to plot the line `x=3` (a line parallel to the y axis where x is 3). I've tried to find an answer on the net, but all the examples always show how to ploy cases of `y=...`, and not the other way around.

I should point out that the graph contains more than one plot (if it matters).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

One way to do this is to use `\addplot  coordinates`.
Or, as Jake suggested one could let the second coordinate be the variable `(3,x)`

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=21.0cm]{geometry}% for image capture
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}\noindent
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$] 
    \addplot[color=red,mark=none, ultra thick]  coordinates {(3,-3) (3,3) };
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[ xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$] 
    \addplot[color=red,mark=none, ultra thick] (3,x);
\end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: who is Jake --`as Jake suggested`

Comment: @jsbibra: Hmmm, a comment must have been deleted. It refers to [Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake).

Answer (score 3):

You could also simply draw anything in TikZ into your axis.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]
    \addplot[color=red,mark=none, ultra thick] {x^2};
    \draw [blue] (axis cs:3,-1000)--(axis cs:3,1001);
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image: Just a line drawn onto the axis]

The axis still clips whatever you draw. This way you can exceed the limits and draw into the enlarged margin. Also you can draw anything you might want and the legend does not get confused.

Comment: Even simpler would be `\draw [blue] (axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymin})--(axis cs:3,\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/ymax});`