# How do I draw a vertical line in a pgfplots plot

Tags: pgfplots

I am trying to draw the line x = 0.9375 but getting an error on this line.

My document is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
 
\title{Reservation pictures}
\author{santanu }
\date{July 2020}

\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\maketitle

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines = left,
    xlabel = $J$,
    ylabel = {$\pi_{d}$},
    xmin=0, xmax=1,
    ymin=0, ymax=1,
]
\addplot [    color=red,
]
{1-01.6*x};
\addlegendentry{$J\,=\,k_{g}\pi_{g}$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
  color=green,
]
{x};
\addlegendentry{$\pi_{d}\,=\,J$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
  color=blue,
]
{1-1.06667*x};
\addlegendentry{$J\,=\,k_{d}\pi_{g}$}
%Here the blue parabloa is defined
\addplot [
  color=black,
]
{x = 0.9375};
\addlegendentry{$J\,=\,k_{d}$}
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Vertical line can be drawn by `\vrule` TeX primitive, for example.

Comment: It is not clear, where you like to have vertical lines. I guess that at `x=0.9375`. I can be drawn by `\addplot [color=black] coordinates {(0.9375,0) (0.9375,1)};`.

Comment: Welcome to Tex.SE! This maybe help: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/91654/31034